Запрос MS SQL в SQLAlchemy ORM
Имею:
def check_conditions_goods_MA_old(db, ma: MarketingActivity, arrGoods: List[NormalizedData_Good])->bool:

    

    # Подготавливаем данные для вставки

    values = []

    params = {}

    

    for i, line in enumerate(arrGoods):

        values.append(f'(:ref_{i}, :quantity_{i})')

        params[f'ref_{i}'] = line.good.code

        params[f'quantity_{i}'] = line.quantity

    params["MA_Ref"] = ma.ref

        

    valuesSQL = ', '.join(values)

    queryPre    = f"""  -- Удаляем временные таблицы, если существуют

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #InputTable;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Goods;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##MA_FilterQuantity;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##MA_FilterGroupsVarious;

                -- Создаем временную таблицу

                CREATE TABLE #InputTable (good_code numeric(7), quantity integer);

                \

                INSERT INTO #InputTable (good_code, quantity)

                VALUES {valuesSQL};

                \

                SELECT

                    Goods.Ref AS Ref,

                    InputTable.Quantity AS Quantity   

                INTO #Goods

                FROM

                    #InputTable AS InputTable

                    INNER JOIN Goods AS Goods

                    ON InputTable.good_code = Goods.Code

                WHERE

                    InputTable.Quantity > 0;   

                \

                SELECT

                    MA.Ref AS MA,

                    Goods.Ref AS Good,

                    MA_GG.KeyField AS KeyField,

                    MA_GG.Quantity AS Quantity,

                    MA_GG.VariousSKU AS VariousSKU,

                    MA_GG.QuantityVarious AS QuantityVarious

                INTO ##MA_FilterQuantity

                FROM

                    _ref_MarketingActivities AS MA

                    INNER JOIN _ref_MarketingActivities_Goods AS MA_Goods

                    ON MA.Ref = MA_Goods.MarketingActivity

                    INNER JOIN _ref_MarketingActivities_GroupsOfGoods AS MA_GG

                    ON MA.Ref = MA_GG.MarketingActivity

                        AND MA_Goods.KeyField = MA_GG.keyField

                    INNER JOIN #Goods AS Goods

                    ON MA_Goods.Element = Goods.Ref

                WHERE

                    MA.Ref = :MA_Ref

                    AND (Goods.Quantity >= MA_GG.Quantity

                        OR Goods.Quantity >= MA_GG.QuantityVarious);

                \

                SELECT

                    MA_FilterQuantity.MA,

                    MA_FilterQuantity.KeyField,

                    MA_FilterQuantity.VariousSKU,

                    COUNT(DISTINCT MA_FilterQuantity.Good) AS QuantitySKU

                INTO ##MA_FilterGroupsVarious   

                FROM

                    ##MA_FilterQuantity AS MA_FilterQuantity

                WHERE

                    MA_FilterQuantity.Quantity >= MA_FilterQuantity.QuantityVarious     

                GROUP BY

                    MA_FilterQuantity.MA,

                    MA_FilterQuantity.KeyField,

                    MA_FilterQuantity.VariousSKU

                HAVING

                    COUNT(DISTINCT MA_FilterQuantity.Good) >= MA_FilterQuantity.VariousSKU;"""

    

    queryMain = f"""SELECT DISTINCT

                    MA_FilterQuantity.MA

                FROM

                    ##MA_FilterQuantity AS MA_FilterQuantity

                WHERE

                    MA_FilterQuantity.VariousSKU = 0

                    AND MA_FilterQuantity.QuantityVarious = 0

                \

                UNION

                \

                SELECT DISTINCT

                    MA_FilterGroupsVarious.MA

                FROM

                    ##MA_FilterGroupsVarious AS MA_FilterGroupsVarious;"""

    

    queryPost = f"""

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #InputTable;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Goods;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##MA_FilterQuantity;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##MA_FilterGroupsVarious;"""

    try:

        with engine.begin() as conn:

            # Выполняем подготовительный запрос

            logging.info(text(queryPre))

            conn.execute(text(queryPre), params)

            # Обрабатываем результаты

            data = conn.execute(text(queryMain)).fetchall()

            result = len(data) > 0

            #logging.info(f'Результат check_ConditionsGoodsMA {ma.code}: {result}')

            #logging.info('Удаляем временные таблицы check_ConditionsGoodsMA.')

            conn.execute(text(queryPost))

            

            return result

        

    except Exception as e:

        logging.error(f'Ошибка при выполнении запросов: {e}')

        raise e

запрос рабочий, но на MS SQL. Хочу преобразовать его с SQL на python ORM alchemy, чтобы вычислялся асинхронно и не городить временные таблицы в SQL.
Начал писать:
async def check_conditions_goods_MA(db, ma: MarketingActivity, arrGoods: List[NormalizedData_Good])->bool:

    query = select(

                    MA_Goods.element,

                    MA_Goods.key_field,

                    MA_GroupsOfGoods.quantity,

                    MA_GroupsOfGoods.quantity_various,

                    MA_GroupsOfGoods.various_sku

            .join(MA_GroupsOfGoods, MA_Goods.key_field == MA_GroupsOfGoods.key_field)

            .join(arrGoods, and_(

                                MA_Goods.element == arrGoods.good,

                                or_(

                                    arrGoods.Quantity >= MA_GroupsOfGoods.Quantity,

                                    arrGoods.Quantity >= MA_GroupsOfGoods.QuantityVarious

                                )

                            )

                )

            .where(

                and_(MA_Goods.marketing_activity == ma,

                     MA_Goods.element.in_(good.ref for good in arrGoods), 

                )

            )

    )

    results = await db.execute(query)

    return results.scalars().all() 

но столкнулся с тем, что могу понять, как указать условие
MA_Goods.element == arrGoods.good,

                                or_(

                                    arrGoods.Quantity >= MA_GroupsOfGoods.Quantity,

                                    arrGoods.Quantity >= MA_GroupsOfGoods.QuantityVarious

В голове есть 2 варианта:

сначала сделать соединение по товарам, а потом фильтроваться по количеству (первичный запрос вернет лишние данные).

передать в запрос список условий с каждой парой товар-количество (будет большое избыточное условие).


Какой правильный подход?
